# using regex with sed on mac doesn't produce expected result

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have file containing following lines that I want to adjust with script.

```js
module.exports = {
  parserOptions: {
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
  },
... more stuff here
}
```

so it looks like this. I dont really care about whitespaces in the result.

```js
module.exports = {
  parserOptions: {
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname
  },
... more stuff here
}
```

What I have now is:

```
sed -r "s/project:\s*\['.\/tsconfig.json'\],/project:\['.\/tsconfig.json'\],\ntsconfigRootDir\:__dirname/g" filename
```

but it doesnt get matched. I tried the matching pattern on this site https://sed.js.org/index.html?snippet=y7KG95 and there I get the result I want. I also tried using `sed -E` but no luck.

I would say the script setup works OK because changing something simple like `s/project/projectA/g` works fine.

Thanks!

Using macOS Monterey 12.5.1

Comment: Which kind of configuration file format it is ?

Comment: javascript file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `-r`, `\s`, and `\n` in the replacement which are all GNUisms (well `\s` is more of a perl'ism). The `\:` is also non-standard. And you have missing `\` in fronts of the `.`s

Standardly, the syntax would be:

```
sed 's@^\([[:blank:]]*\)project:[[:blank:]]*\['\''\./tsconfig\.json'\''\]@&,\
\1tsconfigRootDir: __dirname@g' filename
```

`[[:blank:]]` in place of `\s` (well, `\s` would be more `[[:space:]]` but here it  should be enough to match blanks (`\h` in perl)), `\` followed by newline to include a newline in the replacement.

We capture the leading blanks on the `project` line to indent the added line with the same indentation (`\1` recalls that capture group).

To check the syntax of *your* `sed` implementation and version, check *its* documentation, with `man` or `info`, not some random page on the internet that could be describing a different implementation or version.

See also the POSIX 2018 standard specification of the `sed` utility [there](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sed.html).